# Clearing cells using sheet name variable

Tags: excel, vba

What is this error?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ClearCells ("Sheet1")
    ProcessData
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Sub ClearCells(name As String) 
    Sheets(name).Cells.Clear  'Application-defined or Object-defined error
End Sub
```

It doesn't seems to have any problem. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Make sure that the Worksheet name is the right one - it should work then. just set a Breakpoint and add a watch to Sheets(name).

Comment: Sheet1 is the default one isn't it? I didn't changed the name whatsoever.

Comment: The default name is language based - so its not always a 100% save to assume that it is Sheet1. its the same name which is shown at the bottom where you can switch between the sheets.

Comment: Is the sheet protected?

Comment: @Rory I don't think I have done anything to protect the sheet. I have to double check on some of the settings since the workbooks is taken from another computer.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an ActiveX button in an empty sheet, copying your code into the code of that button and run it (with `ProcessData` being created as a dummy `Sub` just returning, there is nothing wrong with the `...Cells.Clear` method in `Sub ClearCells(...)` ... despite the fact that `name` is kinda "reserved word" ... so not particularly nice to use this as a variable name ... but it works.

The problem for me is `Me.Hide` ... because `Me` here is refering to the Button object on the sheet and this object doesn't have the `Hide` method.

**correction:** based on my assumption where the button is placed, the containing object is a Sheet ... still this object hasn't got the `Hide` method

Comment: No, it isn't - `Me` refers to whatever object contains the button - presumably a userform. ;)

Comment: +1 for pointing this out ... You are correct ... it's a Sheet object (using my assumptions) ... still this object hasn't got a `Hide` method ... I am correcting my post ... guess we need to get a bit more context from the OP

Comment: That's why I assume it's a userform, which does have a Hide method. :)

Comment: @MikeD Me.Hide will throw another error if it is not an userform - but not an object-defined error - more like an illegal use of keyword "ME"

Comment: True, and the same code placed inside a form runs without problems,  as long as the sheet name can be found. If a wrong sheet name is provided, a **Subscript out of range** error is thrown ... which indicates to me that the OP's problem must be different ... maybe he needs to qualify `Sheets(name)` with `Activeworkbook`

Comment: @therak the truth is ... in the code module of a sheet you can't even *enter* `Me.Hide`

Comment: To clarify, I'm using the button on Userform.

Comment: @MikeD - you can, but on compiling it will throw an error :) . Nevertheless it should be the ActiveWorkbook fix - userform isn't in the right context to automatically access the active workbook